# Does the unix words file change over time or between systems?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

Is the Unix "words" file (e.g at `/usr/share/dict/words`) pretty standard? I.e, can I generally rely on, for example, the 200th word in the file to be the same word between a fedora and an ubuntu installation using the same kernel?  Does mac use a different words file?  Does this file get frequently updated with new words, or is the linux words file more-or-less consistent over time?

Comment: Too many questions per question IMO. Also, some of answers are easy to find, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253498/562386

Comment: @Destroy666 this is a great dupe.  Too bad we can't dupe questions across the network...

Answer (score 2):

Tested (OS that support it, use common path):

- `FreeBSD`: installed by default
- `MacOS`: installed by default, package `web2`
- `fedora`: need to install `words` package
- `Debian` and derivative: seems installed by default, package `wamerican`
- `archlinux`: not installed by default, need to install `community/words`
- `Gentoo`: need to install `sys-apps/miscfiles`
- `busybox`: none

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/share/dict/words` is not standard and does not exist on all systems. Its contents depend on how you installed the file.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253498/429691) and [words (Unix) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)).